# MockK creating invalid objects using a private constructor

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Given a wrapper class around a foreign pointer:

```
class CObject private constructor(private val _internalCPointer: Long) {
    external fun doACThing()
    companion object {
        external fun allocate(): CObject
    }
}
```

mockK is generating instances of this object where `_internalCPointer` is 0, leading to segfaults.

How can I tell mockK to use `CObject.allocate` instead of the constructor?

Comment: How mockk is creating this? Have you tried mocking constructor like mockkConstructor(MockCls::class)
every { anyConstructed<MockCls>() } returns ....
?

Comment: @Demigod Tried, but that gave me a different error: `Missing calls inside every { ... } block.`

Comment: It is not clear without a code that tries to mock it) can you provide some?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mockk is unable to mock external methods. So instead I replaced the class with stub kotlin methods, and then I was able to mock it properly.

```
class CObject private constructor(private val _internalCPointer: Long) {
    fun doACThing() = __jni_doACThing
    private external fun __jni_doACThing()
    ...
}
```

I never did figure out how to mock the constructor, but at least CObject can now be used in a mock environment.